# JPA OneToMany - Delete Parent when last Child is deleted

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a `@OneToMany` bi-directional relationship with `@ManyToOne` children. The children are on the owning side.

I want to delete children individually upon user command via the parent and if the last child is removed, then delete the parent.

**Parent.java**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Child> children;
...
```

**Child.java**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Parent parent;
...

void remove(Parent parent, Child child) {
    for(Child c : parent.getChildren()){
        if(c.equals(child)){
            parent.getChildren().remove(c);
            break;
        }
    }

    if(parent.getChildren().isEmpty()){
        parentService.remove(parent);    // *1
    } else {
        parentService.update(parent);    // *2
    }
}
```

The updates at marker `*2` work fine.  But when the last record is found and the code at line marked with `*1` executes I get this exception :

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Removing a detached instance com.package.etc.Parent#18374850; 

nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance com.package.etc.Parent#18374850 at
org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:301)
```

I've tried calling **update** before the **remove**, but get the same exception.

Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK you supposed to load that object first before remove then it will be in persistance state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve it. I hadn't annotated the method @Transactional.